# Redirect loop with node express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have simple webpage with `/about`, `/contact`, `/home` and `/lessons` routes defined. All routes work okay except for `/lessons`. I instantly get a redirect loop (`Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects`).

Here's my main `server.js` code :

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8888;
var app = require('./app').init(port);
var markdown = require('./markdown');
var lessons = require('./lessons.json').lessons;

// app.use(function(req,res,next) {
//     console.log('adding lessons to locals');
//     res.locals.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
//     res.locals.lessons = lessons;
//     next();
// });
// app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('controller is : home');
    res.locals.controller = 'home';
    res.render('home');
});

app.get('/:controller', function (req, res, next) {
  var controller = req.params.controller;
  console.log('controller is : '+ controller);
  if (controller == 'about' || controller == 'contact') {
    res.locals.controller = controller;
    res.render(controller);
  } else {
      console.log('next was taken!');
      next();
  }
});

app.get('/lessons', function(req, res) {
  res.locals.lessons = lessons;
  console.log('controller is : lessons');
  res.render('lessons');
});

app.get('/lessons/:lesson', function(req, res) {
    console.log('controller is : lesson');
    res.locals.controller = 'lessons';
    res.send('gimmie the lesson');
});

/* The 404 Route (ALWAYS Keep this as the last route) */
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    console.log('got 404 request to ' + req.url);
    res.render('404');
});
```

and here's the `app.js`file which is used for server initialization:

```
var express = require('express');
var slashes = require('connect-slashes');


exports.init = function (port) {
  var app = express();
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  // add middleware to remove trailing slash in urls
  app.use(slashes(false));
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.enable("jsonp callback");
  if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler({
      dumpExceptions: true,
      showStack: true
    }));
    app.use(express.logger({
      format: ':method :url'
    }));
  }

  if ('production' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
  }

  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('Oops, something went wrong');
    res.render('500.ejs', {
      locals: {
        error: err
      },
      status: 500
    });
  });

  app.listen(port);

  console.log("Listening on port %d in %s mode", port, app.settings.env);

  return app;
}
```

I have tried debugging the app with `node-inspector` but it's useless since the app doesn't seem to go into any of the `app.get`s to try to match. It immidiately gives me the error when I try to access `localhost:8888/lessons`

**EDIT:**

I think I have found the root of the problem :

- My `/public` dir has a `lessons` folder
- My `/views` dir has a `lessons.ejs` view

When I change `/public/lessons` into `/public/lessons11` for example, the problem is resolved. Can someone explain to me what's express flow in the original scenario that causes the redirect loop ? also, what can I do to resolve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens:

- a request for `/lessons` comes in;
- the static middleware sees the `public/lessons` folder and assumes that's what the intended target is; because it's a folder, it will generate a redirect to `/lessons/` (see below);
- static middleware picks that request up again, but notices there's no `index.html` in that folder, and hands it off to the next middleware (`connect-slashes`);
- the `connect-slashes` middleware removes the trailing slash and issues a redirect to `/lessons`;
- the whole loop starts again;

You can prevent the static middleware from adding a trailing slash, which will fix your redirect loop I think:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { redirect : false }));
```

Comment: Great explanation ! adding `{ redirect : false }` indeed helped. Do you think that the fact that i've disabled static redirect can cause problems in the future? I can, instead, mount all static files calls to `static` prefix : `app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
` What option do you reckon is better ?

Comment: Are you ever going to need the ability to automatically serve `index.html` when someone requests a directory name? If not, I don't think you'll run into problems.

Comment: (although mounting static resources under their own prefix is a cleaner solution)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `express-redirect-loop` middleware.  It uses sessions and you can read more about it and implement it at https://github.com/niftylettuce/express-redirect-loop.